# SQLAlchemy query/filter does not work

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have created a database called `websites2014` and three tables `cand_elec`, `sites`, and `pages` under this database through Postgresql. I am now trying to query the table `pages` and filter by one of its columns `uuid` but it doesn't work. Below is the code:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from sqlalchemy import Column, String  
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import inspect 

db_string = "postgres://usr:passwd@localhost:5432/websites2014"

db = create_engine(db_string)
Session = sessionmaker(db)  
session = Session()

pages = session.query('pages')
```

The codes above work fine until the next line:

```
test = pages.filter_by(uuid="1234").first()
```

It doesn't work if I change the code to:

```
test = pages.filter_by("uuid"="1234").first()
```

I am new to Postgresql and SQLAlchemy. Can anyone help? Thanks!

---

## EDIT 1

Below are the new codes I revised:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
from sqlalchemy import Column, String  
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base  
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import inspect

db_string = "postgres://usr:passwd@localhost:5432/websites2014"

db = create_engine(db_string)
Session = sessionmaker(db)  
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()

class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'polls_question'

    uuid =  Column(String, primary_key=True)  

pages = session.query(Page)  
test = pages.filter_by(uuid=1234).first()
```

However, it gives me an error message as: `InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
 [SQL: 'SELECT polls_question.uuid AS polls_question_uuid \nFROM polls_question \nWHERE polls_question.uuid = %(uuid_1)s \n LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: {'uuid_1': 1234, 'param_1': 1}]`

If I change the last line to: `session.execute("""SELECT * from page WHERE uuid = '1234'""").first()`

It shows another error message as :`InternalError: (psycopg2.InternalError) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
 [SQL: "SELECT * from page WHERE uuid = '1234'"]`

Thanks for the help again!

---

## EDIT 2

As the comments below the answer, if I rewrite the codes as:

```
class Pages(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'

    uuid =  Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

so the class' name and the tablename are defined as I defined when creating the table. It should work and the error message will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use a query object, but it seems you didn't create a mapped class to instantiate it.

[Query documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=filter_by#the-query-object)

[Mapping documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping)

You should declare a class `Page` like the following to use this tool :

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
Base = declarative_base()

class Page(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'

    uuid =  Column(String, primary_key=True)
```

It doesn't need all columns defined in your table, at least the primary key and the columns you will use after in the filter, or in the output you want to create.

Then you can use it to build the `session.query` :

```
pages = session.query(Page)  
test = pages.filter_by(uuid="1234").first()
```

---

Maybe it can be easier to create a simple `SELECT` query statement ?

```
session.execute("""SELECT * from pages WHERE uuid = '1234'""").first()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I'm still a little confused. According to your codes, it seems like even I have already created the table and the columns within it beforehand, I still have to define these two again in my codes? Btw, the last line `test = pages.filter_by(uuid="1234").first()` still doesn't work and I put the error message in my original post.

Comment: @Tzu so sorry about the tablename, it's `__tablename__ = 'page'` of course

Comment: could you check the type of `uuid` in your database ? integer or string ?

Comment: totally no problem. It still gives the same error message but instead in the message it changes `polls_question.uuid` to `page.uuid`.

Comment: `uuid` is defined as `String`

Comment: I think I find the reason. When I created the table through SQLAlchemy, I already gave the class `Page` a tablename as `pages` so when I change the tablename to `pages` the error message disappears. Is the problem solved? (I'm not sure whether I did it correctly)

Comment: yep, i was not very accurate for this tablename... can you print the result of your query ? if so, looks you've got it !

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the uuid correctly.
Please follow the declaration below.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

...

    uuid = db.Column(
        UUID(as_uuid=True),
        nullable=False,
        index=True,
        unique=True,
        server_default=text("uuid_generate_v4()")
    )
```

Comment: According to the [PG uuid-ossp extension docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/uuid-ossp.html), "**Note:** If you only need randomly-generated (version 4) UUIDs, consider using the `gen_random_uuid()` function from the `pgcrypto` module instead." Therefore, I would avoid loading the uuid-ossp extension and instead load pgcrypto and change the last line to `server_default=text("gen_random_uuid()")`.